# How to set the default cursor property of a input text field?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function editButtonClicked(){
    var txtEle = document.getElementById("txtUsername");
    txtEle.style.disabled = false;
    txtEle.style.cursor = "auto";
    txtEle.style.background="white";
}
```

```css
#txtUsername{
  cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txtUsername" value="some text" disabled="disabled">
  <input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="edit" onclick="editButtonClicked()">
</form>
```

[image]

I have a `form` which contain some input text field and edit buttons corresponds to each textfield.
Initially the `textfield` was disable and the cursor property was `not-allowed`. After clicking the `Edit` button i want to enable the `textfield` and set the cursor property to browser default.

```
function btnUEditClick() {
    var txtEle = document.getElementById("txtUsername");
    txtEle.style.disabled = false;
    txtEle.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

But the problem is after setting the cursor property as `default` i cannot edit the `textfield`.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide a functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also click `<>` icon in the header to add a demo. Thanks!

Comment: change the default to auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong method to enable an element and focus on field

This would do

```
function btnUEditClick() {
    var txtEle = document.getElementById("txtUsername");
    txtEle.disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("txtUsername").focus();
}
```

Comment: It would be better to explain _why_ there was a problem. Also, there was no question about focus.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the value of the `disabled` attribute, not a style property. So this line:

```
txtEle.style.disabled = false;
```

Should be this:

```
txtEle.disabled = false;
```